# R: Open websites from a URL string in a data frame

Tags: r

I have an R data frame with a list of 500ish URLs. It looks a bit like this:

```
websites <- data.frame(rbind("www.nytimes.com", "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com"))
```

I want to go through these URLs and open them (maybe 10 at a time) in Google Chrome.

How would I go about this automatically with R?

Comment: Make a loop with sleep, `shell.exec("www.google.com")` ?

Comment: Is the "x at a time" bit important, and do they need to be physically opened in a browser or are you actually interested in scraping data?

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get all 3 of them to open.

```
websites <- data.frame(rbind("www.nytimes.com", "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com"))

websites <- as.data.frame(t(websites))
websites[] <- lapply(websites, as.character)
webVec <- unname(unlist(websites[1,]))

for(i in 1:length(webVec)){
shell.exec(paste(webVec[i]))
}
```

This opens all of them however, and I'm not sure how to open only a certain amount at a time.  I took a stab at it though:

```
setTen <- 1
for(i in (1 * (10 * (setTen - 1))):(10 * setTen )){
shell.exec(paste(webVec[i]))
}
```

the `setTen` variable asks if you want the first ten websites, second ten, ect.

I couldn't test it though since there is only 3 sites in this data frame.
If it doesn't work let me know and I'll try to figure out a different method.